# translating user input in python

Tags: python

I would like to translate items in a list (e.g. `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`) to items in another list (e.g. the names of those numbers).

Furthermore, I want to be able to do the translation so that when a user inputs '1', "one" is printed, and similarly for '2', etc.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 
         'eight', 'nine']
myDict = dict(zip(numbers, names))
```

Comment: Unless I'm reading your question incorrectly, your example is not a dict and those values are certainly not words. It might help if you provided example inputs and outputs.

Comment: You might start out by reading up at http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries . Hint: Python makes this kind of stuff *really* easy, so if your solution looks very complex then you're probably making it harder than you need to.

Comment: i feel the question is still unclear. could you post the sample of data from your dict, and some pairs of input/output example?

Comment: Please clarify what you're asking. It isn't clear from the example, as the input matches the output.

Comment: Ok I edited the post to make it more clear, hope that helps everyone!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`input`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) function will allow you to accept input from the user and do the lookup (if I understand what you are asking):

```
>>> mydict = {'nom':'singe', 'poids':70, 'taille':1.75}
>>> myvar = input()
nom
>>> print(mydict[myvar])
singe
```

Comment: Okay, so when I enter spaces like 1 2 3 it results in an error. how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It will not print "nom piods" because you don't have a key for "nom poids".

This will do what you want:

```
mydict = {'nom':'x', 'poids':'y','foo':'bar'}
print mydict['nom'],mydict['poids']
```

If you will always be using numbers; and not words - you can do this:

```
words = ['zero','one','two','three','four','five']
print words[0] # This will print 'zero'
print words[1] # This will print 'one'

print words['1'] # This will not work, you need to use 1 and not '1'
```